# Python 2.7.6(64-bit) overflow error in primality testing

Tags: python, primes, largenumber

I am running the following code, which is a version of erathosthene's sieve in python 2.7.6 64-bit on win8 on a computer with 4GB RAM.

```
def erathosthenes_sieve2(n):
    '''Tests n>1 primality using improved erathostene's method'''  
    if n==2:  
        return True          
    if n%2==0:  
        return False          
    limit=long(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))  
    for i in xrange(3,limit+1,2):  
       if n%i==0:  
           return False   
    return True
```

When I call this function for sufficiently big numbers, for example 48112959837082048697(which is a prime) i get the following error.

```
erathosthenes_sieve2(48112959837082048697)  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-b0a5b24a8b94> in <module>()
----> 1 erathosthenes_sieve2(48112959837082048697)

D:\repos\PrimalityTests\Eratosthenes2.py in erathosthenes_sieve2(n)
      9         return False
     10     limit=long(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
---> 11     for i in xrange(3,limit+1,2):
     12        if n%i==0:
     13            return False

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

What ways could be used to work around this problem? I know that this is not a good algorithm for testing primes, but this is just a part of my project of comparing efficiency of different primality tests, so please ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `xrange` takes a `C long`, meaning you can't have the arbitrary precision `int`. But there is a way around this. [To quote the docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)

> CPython implementation detail: xrange() is intended to be simple and
>   fast. Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this. The C
>   implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs
>   (“short” Python integers), and also requires that the number of
>   elements fit in a native C long. If a larger range is needed, an
>   alternate version can be crafted using the itertools module:

```
islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step)
```

So in your case:

```
for i in islice(count(3, 2), ((limit+1)-3+2-1+2*(2<0))//2):
    ...
```

Comment: This will take an insane amount of time, my computers hung up when `i = 1249301`, which is 2.596 x 10^-12 % of the way there.